# Akka-HTTP: how to know if Content-type header was explicitly set in received response

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Is the a way in akka-http to know if 'Content-type' header was explicitly set in `HttpResponse` that we received?
From sniffed Http dump I see, that there was no 'Content-Type' header, but

`` httpResponse.header[`Content-Type`].get.contentType.mediaType.toString() `` 
and
`httpResponse.entity.getContentType().mediaType.toString`

stil return `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: I don't think there is such way. But why? Why would you want to know that? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: That is upsetting. I'm testing some HTTP server, and one of the tests requires a check, that server doesn't respond with a Content-Type header.

Answer (score 0):

This is default Content type not only for Akka-HTTP, but perhaps for other frameworks like Play too. Akka-http and other HTTP based technologies need to know how to parse content internally, based on this header. `application/octet-stream` means that it considers request body as just byte-stream.
Rule of thumb: if it is possible - try to specify `Content-type`.